# Zoom images in QTextBrowser

Tags: c++, qt, zooming, qtextbrowser

I have custom text browser class derived from QTextBrowser class.
Also I have QTextDocument in it with formatted html text and several resource images. QTextBrowser has zoom in/zoom out option that make font of document larger or smaller.But the size of all images remains the same.
How can I also change size of all images in QTextDocument while performing zoom in/zoom out?

Comment: As the docs say, QTextEdit zoom methods do not change the size of any images. Using `QWebView` would be a better choice, it zooms images with the rest of the content. `webView->setHtml(textDocument.toHtml())`.

Comment: Can I set QTextDocument into QWebView? I did not find such possibility.

Comment: You can, read the last line of my comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip!
Tell me also please, how can I attach images to my view. When I use QTextDocument with QTextBrowser I add all required images and dynamically generated css as resources into my QTextDocument and all html content are displayed properly. When I use QTextDocument with QWebView I do the same thing but no images displayed in my web view. What do I do wrong?